# What tools can I use for doing this type of semicircular groove?

Tags: tools, router

I have never worked with woodwork and I am very interested in starting to create my first pieces.
Anyway, there is one piece that I have no idea how to do this circular groove. What are the tools for doing this type of circular groove?

[image]

Dimensions:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more context would be helpful. How large is the piece for example? What is it for? How accurate does it need to be? What tools do you have?

I would cut the main curve with a coping saw or bandsaw depending on the size of the piece and then finish it with a spokeshave, spindle sander, or router depending on how accurate it needed to be.

I would then re-saw it into two thin pieces on the bandsaw (or tablesaw) and carve half of the groove in each piece with a router with a ball nose bit. Then I would glue the two pieces back together (after smoothing the mating surfaces).

EDIT: I had a quick look and you can get a 'radius groover' router bit that would allow you to skip the re-saw and re-glue operations. Either way you would need to find a router bit the correct size. What will the radius of the groove be?

EDIT: adding a picture of the radius groover bit.

[image]

Comment: I added the dimensions

Comment: I do not have any tools. I'm looking for information to buy.

Comment: The radius I need is only 9mm.

Comment: You should be able to find a 'radius groover' bit about that size but you might not be able to find one that's exactly 9mm. The name of the bit might also be different depending on where you are.

Comment: Helped me a lot. I am Brazilian and add the mentioned tags I can get better information with suppliers of the region.

Comment: @LCarvalho Routing the groove by cutting the part into two pieces is a good workaround, +1 to Jambo for that. If you go that way the grain of the wood should run vertically, not horizontally or the glue joint will be weak and need reinforcement. BTW, the type of router bit needed for this shape of groove is usually called a *core box* bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect you can cut the circular profile with whatever you like: hole saw if you're lucky, band saw, jig saw, etc. With that done, look for a router bit in a half or full circular shape. You can either edge-route the groove or try to gouge it out with a hand tool. (Plenty of lathe gouges have a round profile.)